Postgres on RDS keeps showing error: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser"
I have a PostgreSQL (engine version 16.3) database on AWS RDS, and a Tomcat webapp on Elastic Beanstalk.
When I tried to connect to the database (with the Java JDBC driver for Postgres, version 42.7.3) I got this error:
FATAL: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver

After a quick google search, I tried to change the "password_encryption" parameter to "md5" in the parameter group associated with my database, and then set a new password to the master user, but now I get this error:
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser"

I doubled checked the connection parameters: my database name, my user name, password, port, host...
This error just won't disappear.
Any ideas???

42.7.3 certainly should support authentication method 10 (SCRAM). So figure out why tomcat is not using the version you think it is.  That could be a security risk.

"password authentication failed" is intentionally vague to avoid disclosing too much to the (presumed hostile) attempted connecting user.  Look in the PostgreSQL database server's log file for the complete error message.
